# How do I have access of all parameters of 4 different intents in 5th intent in dialog flow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have 5 intents taking various inputs from user. I have to display all the taken inputs in last intent. I have used context still it is not working.

Comment: Context is the solution to this issue, can you share how are you trying to set the context and its lifespan?

Answer (score -1):

Use global variables as shown below. Not the best software development practice but works for use in your situation.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

// Once you make it global it will be accessible for the function below

var YourParameter;

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
      YourParameter = agent.parameters.yourParameter

  }
});
```

Comment: This will only work if you are the only user of your bot. If a different conversation comes though the handler it will set the variable to something else and change it for every conversation that is being handled. So this isnt a very usable sollution

Comment: Without using webhook can we have access to all variables?